# 400 bad request with ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

I have used this before, and it has worked all the times:

```
library("ggmap")
newmap2<-get_openstreetmap(bbox = c(left = -71.2612362452596, 
bottom = 42.3308503846824, right = -71.0475647202879,
top = 42.4560226746649), scale=80000)
```

Now, all I can get is the following error message:

In download.file(url, destfile = destfile, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") :
URL 'http://tile.openstreetmap.org/cgi-bin/export?bbox=-71.2612362452596,42.3308503846824,-71.0475647202879,42.4560226746649&scale=80000&format=png': status was '400 Bad Request'

I have used both the package ggmap v. 2.6.1 (from CRAN) and 2.7 (from GITHUB). Any help is appreciated.
G

Comment: Did you get what you were looking for? :)

Comment: Possibly related to: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/53853/cannot-get-mapnik-image-from-exportfinish-with-python

Answer (score 4):

The process seems to be very resource intensive, and that's why the code doesn't works. Read the discussion here: 
Updated link: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/25637/i-am-receiving-a-blank-page-http11-400-bad-request-after-requesting-a-data-export

Quote from the link:

> Background: The export feature needs much processing power, which our
>   servers are short of (just donated resources!). It could be that it
>   works during a low load time

I tried the same location bounding box using `"google"` as map source and it worked:

```
newmap4 <- get_map(location = c(-71.2612362452596,42.3308503846824
                                ,-71.0475647202879,42.4560226746649), source = 'google')
```

Comment: Yes it works with both google and stamen, not with OSM. OSM worked 3-4 days ago with the same line. The link you provided indicates a different error (503) for service overload

Comment: @GiuseppeBarbesino Sorry, that was the wrong link that I added. Look at this one. I hope it helps you, again talks about resource intensive usage and unavailability.