# trouble getting satellite maps with ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

The code recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526370/400-bad-request-with-ggmap), to download and plot a google map with ggmap works for me.

```
newmap4 <- get_map(location = c(-71.2612362452596,42.3308503846824
                            ,-71.0475647202879,42.4560226746649), source = 'google')

 p <- ggmap(newmap4)
 p
```

However, I'd really like to be able to be able to plot satellite maps, rather than terrain maps. I tried that as follows.

```
newmap5 <- get_map(location = c(-71.2612362452596,42.3308503846824
                            ,-71.0475647202879,42.4560226746649), source = 'google',
               maptype = "satellite")

 p <- ggmap(newmap5)
 p
```

In this case, the map that R prints out looks identical to the newmap 4 example above. Any advice?

```
 Sys.info()
```

> ```
>  sysname 
>                                       "Linux" 
>                                       release 
>                              "4.4.0-1083-aws" 
>                                       version   "#93-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 8 16:08:41 UTC 2019" 
>                                      nodename  "application-997622-deployment-3251181-722tz" 
>                                       machine 
>                                      "x86_64" 
>                                         login 
>                                     "unknown" 
>                                          user 
>                                "rstudio-user" 
>                                effective_user 
>                                "rstudio-user"
> ```

Comment: Enabling Static API in Google Cloud solved this for me

Answer (score 1):

Try the same code using `get_googlemap()` instead of `get_map()`. I'm not sure why that is required, since you specify that the source is Google. Have you registered your Google API key?

```
register_google(key = "<your key here>")
newmap5 <- get_googlemap(location = c(-71.2612362452596,42.3308503846824
                            ,-71.0475647202879,42.4560226746649), source = 'google',
               maptype = "satellite")
ggmap(newmap5)
```

[image: map]